# Detect First Character in Line 1 Using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++ I want to remove the first 2 characters in the line 1 in each file. How do I detect the first 2 characters in line 1 only? There are similar characters in other parts of the file that I dont want to remove. I am trying to detect these two characters using regex but I could not find a way to detect the first 2 characters in line 1 using regex.

To be more clear I provide a screenshot.

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards, Darnin.

[image: Remove 2 character in line 1 every file]

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++'s regex appears to support the `\A` start-of-file [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

So this regex matches those two characters at start of file only:

`\A(\?>)`